# psql query number of rows in multiple tables and save in variable

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

I'm trying to query the total number of records across multiple PostgreSQL tables in a shell script.

The shell script is to be executed by a build pipeline and the pipeline needs to know the number of total number of rows.

**shell script**

```
docker run -it postgres psql "host=xxx.com port=5432 dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxxw" -f row_count.sql
```

**row_count.sql**

```
select SUM(row_count)
from (
    SELECT count(*) as row_count
    FROM "table_a"
    union all
    SELECT count(*) as row_count
    FROM "table_b"
    union all
    SELECT count(*) as row_count
    FROM "table_c"
) as total
```

I have tested my query and it's fine, but having difficulty reading the sql file from the `psql` command and I'm not sure how to save the number of records in a variable to be read by the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

to execute a command in an shell script, use backticks.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands
So your command will look like that:

```
PGRESULT=`docker run -it postgres psql "host=xxx.com port=5432 dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxxw" -f row_count.sql`
```

the result is stored in PGRESULT. Read the manpage to psql, maybe adding some parameters to psql helps further working with values in PGRESULT.

> -t
> --tuples-only
> Turn off printing of column names and result row count footers, etc. This is equivalent to \t or \pset tuples_only.
>
> -c command
> --command=command
> Specifies that psql is to execute the given command string, command. This option can be repeated and combined in any order with
> the -f option. When either -c or -f is specified, psql does not
> read commands from standard input; instead it terminates after processing all the -c and -f options in sequence.
>
> -A
> --no-align
> Switches to unaligned output mode. (The default output mode is otherwise aligned.) This is equivalent to \pset format unaligned.
>
> -F separator
> --field-separator=separator
> Use separator as the field separator for unaligned output. This is equivalent to \pset fieldsep or \f.

Comment: Thanks I have decided to incorporated that in a psql function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008908/plpgsql-function-return-true-the-number-of-records-across-multiple-tables-great