# Function testing whether number of rows across multiple tables is greater than supplied int param

Tags: postgresql, count, plpgsql

I'm trying to write an PL/pgSQL function that returns a boolean: `true`, if the total number of rows across multiple tables is greater or equal than the supplied int parameter, else `false`. But not having much luck.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION allrecordsHaveUpdated (numberOfRecords int)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
declare
    totalRecords integer;
    recordsInserted boolean := false;

BEGIN
    totalRecords = (select SUM(row_count)
    from (
        SELECT count(*) as row_count
        FROM "table_1"
        union all
        SELECT count(*) as row_count
        FROM "table_2"
        union all
        SELECT count(*) as row_count
        FROM "table_3"
    ) as total)

    IF totalRecords >= numberOfRecords THEN
        recordsInserted = true;
    END IF;
    RETURN recordsInserted;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Seems like your function should work fine. Don't forget to add ```semicolon``` after ```total)```

Comment: You don't actually need PL/pgSQL for this however.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing strictly wrong in your function is the missing semicolon after the first assignment.

But the whole thing is overblown. Burns down to just:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION all_records_updated (_number_of_records int)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM table_1)
     + (SELECT count(*) FROM table_2)
     + (SELECT count(*) FROM table_3) >= _number_of_records
$func$;
```

`count()` never returns NULL, so the plain addition never fails.

Related:

- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)

Legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers make your life in Postgres easier. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Answer (score 0):

Try a SQL function rather than a plpgsql function:

```
create or replace function allrecordshaveupdated (numberofrecords int)
 returns boolean 
 language sql
as $$
    select sum(row_count) > numberofrecords
      from (select count(*) as row_count from "table_1" 
            union all
            select count(*) from "table_2" 
            union all
            select count(*) from "table_3" 
          ) as total;
 $$;
```